# Showing that a measurable function $\phi$ is in $L^\infty$ if $\phi f \in L^2$ for each $f \in L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Here's what I am trying to show:

Suppose $\varphi $ is a Borel measurable function on $[0,1]$ such that $\varphi f \in L^2[0,1]$ for every $f\in L^2[0,1].$ Consider the map $M_{\varphi} : L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ defined by $M_{\varphi}(f) = \varphi f$ for every $f\in L^2[0,1].$ Prove that $M_{\varphi}$ is continuous linear transformation and $\varphi \in L^{\infty}[0,1].$

---

What follows is my haphazard attempt:

I am aware that there is a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3182444/151611) but I would like use tools from Functional Analysis to prove this. I am trying to use the following result to prove this:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. If $(T_n)$ is a sequence of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$ such that for every $x\in X$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} T_n(x)$ exists, then $T(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} T_n(x)$ is a bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Y$.

I have not been able to complete this but if I can show that $\varphi \in L^{\infty} [0,1]$ then the continuity of $M_\varphi$ follows easily.

Since the constant function $1\in L^2 [0,1]$ we have that $\varphi \in L^2[0,1]$ by our assumption.

I managed to show that $M_\varphi : L^2 [0,1] \to L^1 [0,1]$ given by $M_\varphi (f) = \varphi f$ for every $f \in L^2 [0,1]$ is continuous.

Since the continuous functions are dense in $L^2[0,1]$, we can find a sequence of continuous functions $g_n \in C[0,1]$ such that $\lVert g_n - \phi \rVert _2 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Consider the sequence $M_{\varphi_n} : L^2 [0,1] \to L^1 [0,1]$ given by $M_{\varphi_n} (f) = f \varphi_{n}$ for each $f \in L^2 [0,1]$. Then $M_{\varphi_n} (f) \to M_{\varphi} (f)$ in $1$-norm for every $f \in L^2 [0,1]$. Therefore, $M_\varphi$ is bounded.

---

Hints on solving this problem will be appreciated!

Comment: You proved that $M_\varphi : L^2 [0,1] \to L^1 [0,1]$ is continuous. But you have to show that  $M_\varphi : L^2 [0,1] \to L^2 [0,1]$ is continuous.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, I know. That was an attempt on my part by weakening the hypothesis a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \phi_n=\phi 1_{|\phi| \leq n}$ and $M_{\phi_n}f=\phi_n f$. Then $\int |\phi_n -\phi|^{2}|f|^{2} \to 0$ by DCT and the fact that $\int |\phi f|^{2}<\infty$. Hence, $M_{\phi_n}f \to M_{\phi}f$ in $L^{2}$ for every $f$ and the result you have quoted proves that $M_{\phi}f$ is continuous. To show that $\phi \in L^{\infty}$ you have to show that $\|M_{\phi_n}\|=\|\phi_n\|_{\infty}$ and apply Uniform Boundedness Principle.

Hint for showing that $\|M_{\phi_n}\|=\|\phi_n\|_{\infty}$: Take $f=c\, sgn( \phi_n)1_A$ where $c$ is a normalizing constant and $A=\{x: |\phi_n(x)|>\|\phi_n\|_{\infty}-\epsilon\}$.